# Calculating an average within a JavaScript function using arguments

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to define teams with 4 different attributes -- speed, header, power, and accuracy. Then, I want to find the average of theses 4 attributes, but for some reason when I try to do so, or perform any mathematical operation between attributes, the program returns undefined. Any ideas?

```
team1 = new team ("Manchester United");
team2 = new team ("Arsenal");
team3 = new team ("Chelsea");
team4 = new team ("New York Rangers");

function soccerGame (team1, team2, team3, team4)  {

var team = function(teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ; 
    this.header = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    this.power = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    this.accuracy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    console.log(this.accuracy + this.power + this.header + this.speed) / 4;
};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var team = function(teamName) {
    this.teamName = teamName;
    this.speed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ; 
    this.header = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    this.power = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    this.accuracy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    console.log(this.accuracy + this.power + this.header + this.speed) / 4;
};


team1 = new team ("Manchester United");
team2 = new team ("Arsenal");
team3 = new team ("Chelsea");
team4 = new team ("New York Rangers");
```

Your `team` function and arragement of code does matter.

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/2J6pL/)

Comment: Order only matters because a function expression is being used. If the OP used a function declaration, it wouldn't matter (but would still be better if the function declaration was first).

Comment: I mean the `var team = function(team)` should place outside the `soccerGame` function. That is my meaning of arragement of code.

Comment: Ok. You may have guessed I'm not a fan of using function expressions where function declarations can be used. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your only issue is that you have your constructor wrapped in `soccerGame`, making it a local variable. Local variables can only be accessed from within the scope of the function. You have two options: put your `team` declarations within the `soccerGame` function, or remove the function and implement what you were planning to do with that somewhere else. You can't pass in teams to it if you define your `team`s within the function, so I would recommend the second option.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/5R43n/)